# Swap rank in firebase realtime database using cloud function - Game

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, libgdx, google-cloud-functions

I have a database which has all users_ID with rank and x_location.
I am trying to listen for x_location update and get rank,x_location and user_ID from `onUpdate()` triggering method in Firebase cloud function. But how could I directly get preceding rank user details to check if that user's x_location is less than the current user's x_location to swap rank?

I have the final approach to traverse all users to find the preceding rank user and guess changes, but I am wondering for a more precise and optimized method to achieve this. Traversing all user_ID looks memory consuming task.

I would also mention this function has to run for multiple users updates, which may be huge processing with the bulk of data.

For the current scenario, I am just collecting all the details for the updated user.

**My Firebase database snapshot:**

```
users
 |- -kSjJSDFjl2DFc
 |        |- rank: 2
 |        |- x_location: 500
 |- -laoeSDFjfkdie
 |        |- rank: 1
 |        |- x_location: 600
 |
 So on...
```

**My swap function in firebase cloud function:**

```
//rank swap function
exports.swapRank = functions.database.ref('/users/{userID}').onUpdate(event => {
    var xVal = 0;   //updated user x_location
    var cxVal = 0;  //current preceding user x_location
    var rVal = 0;   //updated user rank
    var crVal = 0;  //current preceding user rank
    var uVal = event.params.userID;  //updated user_ID
    var cuVal = "";                  //current preceding user_ID
    return event.after.ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
                if(child.key === 'x')      //updated user x_location
                    xVal = child.val();
                else if(child.key === 'r') //updated user rank
                    rVal = child.val();
        });

//*********************************************************************
        //preceding rank details collection needed here
        //cxVal,crVal,cuVal;
//*********************************************************************

        //To implement
        //if((crVal==(rVal-1)) & cxVal<xVal)
        //swap user ranks in firebase database;
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that you want to swap the user with `rank: 2` with the player before it. You could get those from the database with this query:

```
firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild("rank").endAt(2).limitToLast(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. Got an idea from your code and followed docs at [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) to solve my problem. I was not aware of Firebase queries. Never mind I am brand new in cloud functions (Specially node.js).